# highcharts categories display in PDF

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to display all the categories on downloaded PDF. But, i am not able to see the all the categories in my current downloaded PDF. Can i achieve this?

Here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/manraj/7racxxu0/10

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['ghdg', 'kndfkjl', 'ytryr', 'Bananas', 'pop', 'errte', 'oi', 'Oranges1', 'Bananas1', 'Carrots1', 'Appls2', 'Pears2', 'wosflsj', 'ertet', 'yuyu', 'Ales', 'ioi', 'opl', 'bcvcx', 'Carots', 'Apes1', 'opop', 'Oranges1', 'yuiiui', 'Carrots1', 'errt', 'oioi', 'ioo', 'Bananas2', 'bfhjf', 'Apples', 'xxcc', '6546', 'Bananas', '646', 'tyuyf', 'rtr', 'rty', 'opuuui', 'fghf', 'tyuy', 'err', 'rewporij', 'xcvgff', 'ee', 'bvnvb', 'bnn', 'kjhfkdg', 'tytryt', '2121', 'Apples1', 'xvx', 'iyyuy', 'bnbn', 'yuyu', 'fgs', 'Pears2', 'orwuepr', 'ppwppw', 'Crots2', 'Apes', '545', 'nmvh', '855963', '96489', 'iuio', '8998', 'ghtrf', 'nff', 'Cats1', 'Apes2', '2333', 'itrosfgn', 'Banas2', 'zasar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        min: 100
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }],
     exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 1200,
            sourceHeight: 600, 

            chartOptions: {
                xAxis: [{
                    categories: ['ghdg', 'kndfkjl', 'ytryr', 'Bananas', 'pop', 'errte', 'oi', 'Oranges1', 'Bananas1', 'Carrots1', 'Appls2', 'Pears2', 'wosflsj', 'ertet', 'yuyu', 'Ales', 'ioi', 'opl', 'bcvcx', 'Carots', 'Apes1', 'opop', 'Oranges1', 'yuiiui', 'Carrots1', 'errt', 'oioi', 'ioo', 'Bananas2', 'bfhjf', 'Apples', 'xxcc', '6546', 'Bananas', '646', 'tyuyf', 'rtr', 'rty', 'opuuui', 'fghf', 'tyuy', 'err', 'rewporij', 'xcvgff', 'ee', 'bvnvb', 'bnn', 'kjhfkdg', 'tytryt', '2121', 'Apples1', 'xvx', 'iyyuy', 'bnbn', 'yuyu', 'fgs', 'Pears2', 'orwuepr', 'ppwppw', 'Crots2', 'Apes', '545', 'nmvh', '855963', '96489', 'iuio', '8998', 'ghtrf', 'nff', 'Cats1', 'Apes2', '2333', 'itrosfgn', 'Banas2', 'zasar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    min: 0,
                    max: 113
                }]
            }
        }
});
```

});

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bug in exporting module - set `xAxis: [{ ... }]` in options for a chart too, see: http://jsfiddle.net/7racxxu0/13/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['ghdg', 'kndfkjl', 'ytryr', 'Bananas', 'pop', 'errte', 'oi', 'Oranges1', 'Bananas1', 'Carrots1', 'Appls2', 'Pears2', 'wosflsj', 'ertet', 'yuyu', 'Ales', 'ioi', 'opl', 'bcvcx', 'Carots', 'Apes1', 'opop', 'Oranges1', 'yuiiui', 'Carrots1', 'errt', 'oioi', 'ioo', 'Bananas2', 'bfhjf', 'Apples', 'xxcc', '6546', 'Bananas', '646', 'tyuyf', 'rtr', 'rty', 'opuuui', 'fghf', 'tyuy', 'err', 'rewporij', 'xcvgff', 'ee', 'bvnvb', 'bnn', 'kjhfkdg', 'tytryt', '2121', 'Apples1', 'xvx', 'iyyuy', 'bnbn', 'yuyu', 'fgs', 'Pears2', 'orwuepr', 'ppwppw', 'Crots2', 'Apes', '545', 'nmvh', '855963', '96489', 'iuio', '8998', 'ghtrf', 'nff', 'Cats1', 'Apes2', '2333', 'itrosfgn', 'Banas2', 'zasar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        min: 100
    }],
    ...
});
```

Comment: Still it is not exporting all the chart data to single pdf. it only exporting visible area of the chart. I want to export all the chart data into pdf with displaying all the categories on axis.

Comment: Which browser are you using? My example/jsfiddle works perfectly fine on Chrome.

Comment: I am using Chrome too but i did not see all the data on downloaded PDF . I see only the visible chart area in fiddle that too some missing categories names on y-axis.

Comment: Yes, there are missing categories on xAxis (not yAxis). but that's caused by not enough height on a chart.. Anyway, I still see all data points on a chart (well, 113 at least).

Comment: Yeah, it was xAxis, Changed the Sourcewidth or hight but that at all not working. Is there any way that i can see all the chart data into single or multiple page pdf with displaying all the categories on axis without missing. Does highcharts support this?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7racxxu0/14/ ? I can see now all categories and all points, is that what you expected?

Comment: I ran into issue after i want to display almost 1000 categories on axis and i put Sourcewidth and SourceHeight as 8000 or more. Still i see some missing data on downloaded PDF. i am getting high charts error on browser console as http://www.highcharts.com/errors/10. Is there any limit on exporting?

Comment: That error means you are using logarithmic axis and trying to display something like -100, -0.53, 0 etc. numbers, which can't be plotted.